# is it incorrect to change a model's parameters after training it?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, ensemble-learning

i was trying to use average ensembling on a group of models i trained earlier (i'm creating a new model in the ensemble for each pre-trained model i'm using and then loading the trained weights onto it, it's inefficient this way i know but i'm just learning about it so it doesn't really matter). and I mistakenly changed some of the network's parameters when loading the models in the ensemble code like using Relu instead of leakyRelu which i used in training the models and a different value for an l2 regularizer in the dense layer in one of the models. this however gave me a better testing accuracy for the ensemble. can you please explain to me if/how this is incorrect, and if it's normal can i use this method to further enhance the accuracy of the ensemble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it is NOT correct to chnage model's `parameters` after training it. `parameters` here I mean the `trainable-parameters` like the weights in Dense node but not hyper-parameters like learning rate.

**What is training?**

Training essentially is a loop that keeps changing, or update, the `parameters`. It updates the `parameter` in such a way that it believes it can reduce the loss. It is also like moving your *point* in a hyper-spaces that the loss function gives a small loss on that *point*.

Smaller loss means higher accruacy in general.

**Changing Weights**

So now, changing your `parameters` values, by mistake or by purpose, is like moving that *point* to somewhere BUT **you have no logical reason behind that such move will give you a smaller loss**. You are just randomly wandering around that hyper-space and in your case you are just lucky that you land to some *point* that so happened give you a smaller loss or a better testing accuracy. It is just purely luck.

**Changing activation function**

Also, altering the activation function from `leakyRelu` to `relu` is similar you randomly alter the shape of your hype-space. Even though you are at the some *point* the landscape changes, you are still have no logical reason to believe by such change of landscape you can have a smaller loss staying at the same *point*

When you change the model manually, you need to retrain.

Answer (score 0):

Though you changed the network's parameters when loading the models. It is not incorrect to alter the hyper-parameters of your ensemble's underlying models. In some cases, the models that are used in an ensemble method require unique tunings which can, as you mentioned, give "you a better testing accuracy for the ensemble model."

To answer your second question,  you can use this method to further enhance the accuracy of the ensemble, you can also use Bayesian optimization, GridSearch, and RandomSearch if you prefer more automated means of tuning your hyperparameters.